# How to set a value on a field collection using entity metadata wrapper

Tags: 7, entities

I'm trying to programmatically set a value on a field collection item attached to the user entity.

The field collection field in question is titled, `field_user_location`.

I initially had this ($usr_wrapper being an entity metadata wrapper of the user entity)

```
$usr_wrapper->field_user_location->field_land_phone->set($object['Phone Number']);
```

However that doesn't appear to work.

How do you get data onto a field collection via `entity_metadata_wrapper()`? There isn't much documentation about how to do this that I am seeing.

Answer (score 4):

I found the documentation for field collections confusing as well.

Field collections need their own entity metadata wrapper. So, the following code would work for your example:

```
$collection = entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => 'field_user_location'));
$collection->setHostEntity('user', $user);
$fc_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $collection);
$fc_wrapper->field_land_phone->set($object['Phone Number']);
```

I hope that helps for anyone else banging their heads over this.

Comment: Just for clarification, what is `$object`? Just a newly-instatiated array named 'object'?

Comment: In this example, we don't know exactly what `$object` was. We only know that it was an array that had a key named 'Phone Number'. The important thing as far as entity metadata wrappers are concerned is that the `set` method receives an argument that matches the data structure of the field to which it's attached. So, if the `field_land_phone` is a textfield that holds a string value, you pass it the string you want to set it to. That line could just have easily read `$fc_wrapper->field_land_phone->set('867-5309');`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, the could should be:

```
global $user;
$usr_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user);

// Create the collection entity and set its "host".
$field_collection_item = entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => 'field_user_location')); // Name of collection field.
$field_collection_item->setHostEntity('node', $usr_wrapper->value());

// Now define the collection parameters.
$collection = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $field_collection_item);
$collection->field_land_phone = "0123"; // array("0123") in case of multi-valued field.
// $collection->field_land_phone->set("0123"); // Version using set(), use: set(array("0123")) for multi-valued field.

// Save.
$collection->save(); // Or: $usr_wrapper->save();
```

Also check [Entity metadata wrappers](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers) documentation page (check for *Example using field collections*).

---

Here is another example which adds an entry to a node with a field collection named `field_activity_log`:

```
  // Load the controller class file.
  module_load_include('inc', 'entity', 'includes/entity.controller');

  // Use the currently logged in user if a $uid argument is not defined.
  global $user;
  if (empty($uid)) {
    $uid = $user->uid;
  }

  $now = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // Grab the current time.

  // Setup the values in the structure expected by the field_collection entity.
  $values = array(
    'field_name' => 'field_activity_log',
    'field_activity_log_date' => array(
      LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $now)),
    ),
    'field_activity_log_message' => array(
      LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $message)),
    ),
    'field_activity_log_user' => array(
      LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('uid' => $uid)),
    ),
  );
  $entity = entity_create('field_collection_item', $values);

  // Attach the field_collection entity to the application node. This has to
  // happen separately so that it actually works -- you can't just specify
  // this via the $values array.
  $entity->setHostEntity('node', $node);

  // Save the entity. Since it's attached to the right application node, this
  // will both create the field_collection entity and update the application
  // node to point to the new field_activity_log record.
  $entity->save();
?>
```

Source: [Example: Programmatically adding field collection entries to a node](https://www.drupal.org/node/1477186)

And this example shows updating (loading/editing/saving) an existing field collection in an Entity Wrapper:

```
<?php
// Load the node by NID
$raw_node = node_load($nid);
// Wrap it with Entity API
$node = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $raw_node);
// Get the first item from the muli-value field collection
$raw_collection = $node->field_collection->value();
// Wrap it with Entity API
$collection = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $raw_collection);
//dsm the old value
dsm($collection->field_example->value());
// Set a new value on the field_example textfield.
$collection->field_example = 'New value';
// Save the changes to the entity
$collection->save();
?>
```

Source: [Example: Programmatically create and update field collection with Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/node/1842304)

---

#### Troubleshooting

In case of error when setting the data value with `set()`, be be sure it matches the required data type and format. If your entity won't get saved, check for the logs for any wrapper exceptions (`drush ws --tail`).

See also: [Modifying a field collection programmatically missing hostEntity fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17731629/55075) at SO